# Does bank will share our address with others?

Tags: bank-account

Actually i given a check of rs 10,000 to my friend but my friend misused to and given to some one with whom he had to pay same amount..And i couldn't maintain the same amount in my bank as it is my salary account,without to my notice that person went to bank and asked for my contact no.Hdfc bank provided my number along with the address.
Is it correct?if it is any other cases it would be very tough for the users,how can they just provide the address with out our notice?

Comment: Please add a country tag. Bank regulations and privacy laws differ by country.

Comment: Isn't your address on the check?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Address isn't _always_ printed on checks, but it's common for folks to include it, since otherwise many vendors would ask you to add it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to consult your bank's privacy policy. The answer will be specific to the bank unless you are in a country (for example an EU country) with stricter privacy laws. (And even then, some banks may be stricter than the law requires while others may just meet the letter of the law.)

Comment: rs = rupees = INDIA, so I added country tag :)

Comment: @uDaY - you just posted a question saying you were in Massachusetts, US. Why are you using multiple SE IDs?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer lol! the person who posted the question is not me. I am just helping the community. I said i live in MA but I didnt say that I was an Indian by Nationality ;)

Comment: The rupee is the common name for the currencies of India, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Nepal, Mauritius, Seychelles, Maldives, Indonesia. OP may very well be from India, but s/he should tell us.

Comment: The user also said it was HDFC back which operates only in Ind. so was my conclusion ;)